# Check if array element contains part of value in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make a third array out of two arrays. I want to check if  array 2 contains array 1 elements.

So Array2 could look like:

```
["Bol Sales ", "BookStore Amazon Sales", "Nintendo Sales", "XBOX" ]
```

Array 1:

```
["Bol", "Amazon","XBOX"]
```

Array 3 should then be:

```
["Bol", "Amazon", "XBOX"]
```

But most of the outcomes are only XBOX (so, array1.val full match array2.val).

I've tried the following:

```js
var array1 = ["Bol", "Amazon", "XBOX"],
  array2 = ["Bol Sales ", "BookStore Amazon Sales", "Nintendo Sales", "XBOX"],
  array3 = [];


array3 = array1.filter(function(store) {
  return array2.includes(store);
});
console.log(array3);

array3 = array1.filter(function(store) {
  return array2.indexOf(store) >= 0;
});
console.log(array3);

var storesToCheck = function(array1, array2) {
  return array1.some(function(value) {
    return array2.indexOf(value) >= 0;
  });
};

console.log(storesToCheck(array1, array2));
```

Comment: Please note the snippet I made for you. It is called a [mcve] - please provide such a thing in the future after some research.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `includes` method in combination with `some` by passing a *callback* provided function as argument.

```js
arr2 = ["Bol Sales ", "BookStore Amazon Sales", "Nintendo Sales", "XBOX" ]
arr1 =  ["Bol", "Amazon","XBOX"]

console.log(arr1.filter(a => arr2.some(item => item.includes(a))));
```

Comment: If arr2 = ["Bol Sales ", "BookStore Amazon Sales", "Nintendo Sales", "XBOX" ] and arr1 =  ["Bol", "Amazon","XBOX","Sales"]

Your code Output is  ["Bol", "Amazon","XBOX","Sales"]... So kindly check your logic...